# Sublime Text 2 Plugin Development Trace Variable

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a way to dump a variable into the command prompt. For example, if I have the following:

```
 def (self, edit):
      myvar = 'this is a string'
```

I would like to call a method that would show the value of `myvar` in the Sublime Command Prompt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python, but Sublime is just showing you a Python compiler. So you can just use the following to print to the command line:

```
print(myvar)
```